# delete by query request on embedded elasticsearch returns error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an unit test that starts an embedded elasticsearch (version 5.2.1). The basic APIs work with apache HttpClient requests. But the `_delete_by_query` throws following error

Request

```
 POST http://localhost:54921/INDEX/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "journalId": {
        "value": "11111"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
                "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_delete_by_query]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
        "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_delete_by_query]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I tried adding document type to the URL (`POST http://localhost:54921/INDEX/TYPE/_delete_by_query`) but then it returns 201.

Seems that the embedded server does not get `_delete_by_query` implementation. I also tried adding dependency to `reindex-client` but nothing seems to work.

Note that if I execute the same request on my standalone server, it works properly.

Comment: Can you also show the query you send to the `_delete_by_query` endpoint?

Comment: nevermind, I figured out that I need to initialize the node with `ReindexPlugin`, doesn't work with just the compile time dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to enable `_delete_by_query` API by adding `ReindexPLugin`

```
val elasticSearchSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put("http.enabled", "true")
            .put("transport.type", "netty4")
            .put("http.type", "netty4")
            .put("http.port", port)
            .put("path.data", dataDirectory)
            .put("path.home", dataDirectory)
        node = MyNode(elasticSearchSettings.build(), listOf(Netty4Plugin::class.java, ReindexPlugin::class.java)).apply { start() }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `type` name between `index` and `_delete_by_query`, like:

```
POST http://localhost:54921/INDEX/TYPE_NAME/_delete_by_query
```

Where `TYPE_NAME` is index type that you want to remove from.